# Remap Ctrl+F to Find instead of Forward in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

Can Ctrl+F be remapped to Find instead of Forward in Outlook? To be honest it would be much more useful that way to me as I frequently want to search within a message and right now I have to click on the Find button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The origin of this abomination is a demand in 1995 by a beta-tester of Outlook,
whose name just happened to be Bill Gates.
For details see
[Why does Outlook map Ctrl+F to Forward instead of Find, like all right-thinking programs?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140715-00/?p=503)

This hotkey is actually the <kbd>F4</kbd>.

If you would like to change it, this is possible using a
[AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) script:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32
^f::Send, {F4}
```

Comment: This AutoHotKey tip is confusing. How or why would it work only on Outlook?

Comment: @JariTurkia: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm

Comment: Yes `#IfWinActive` is nearly self-explanatory. The part where it specifies Outlook 2002, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016 or 2019 is ambiguous.

Comment: @JariTurkia: Please read the documentation : https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm. There is of course no guarantee that Microsoft might not change `ahk_class` in the future.

Comment: I'm just doing my due diligence here. For that window class the best documentation seems to be http://users.skynet.be/am044448/Programmeren/VBA/vba_class_names.htm